# How to copy plain text value from using Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function copytext(text) {
    var textField = document.createElement('textarea');
    textField.innerText = text;
    document.body.appendChild(textField);
    textField.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    textField.remove();
}
```

I found this code on Reddit and I thought it would work as it was logical to create a element then SELECT IT then after that execute the command 'copy'. But I was surprised that it didn't and I do not know why.

No error is given when running this script on Chrome Dev Console which is where I want to execute it and that's exactly why I don't want to hear as an answer **ANY API** that has to do with copying. If you can tell me how to use an API on chrome dev tools then feel free to let me know about that.

If there are some things I left out or you have questions about.

Comment: I think you are asking more about the document object model than about javascript. Sadly, the DOM is implemented very inconsistently, so code you find that works in one browser can easily fail (or have no effect) in another. (I don't have an answer, just helping you craft the question, and understand why it's difficult).

Comment: Copying is actually 2 actions in 1. First read the value of the text area. Second Duplicate the value. I cant tell you where it's in error because you have not given any code relating to how it is reading the value i.e. what does `textField.select()` do?

Comment: @MatthewRath I believe it selects all content within the textbox.

Comment: You are better off prompting the user to use to use CTRL+C/ CMD+C to copy things into their clipboard, because due to security settings, relying on the `execCommand()` is very unreliable. Some browsers may allow it, many won't. You can pre-select the text to help the user out, but keep in mind that your current function technically selects the entire textarea object, not just the text. Depending on where you copy it to, this could cause issues.

Comment: Its not supported in all browsers as @JamesNewton points out. Most of the APIs that work in these browsers use a Flash or HTML5 based workaround. 
https://github.com/patricklodder/jquery-zclip/blob/master/jquery.zclip.js#L139

Comment: @Battle_707 I came to that method as well and is my current method. But I was just asking as being able to copy to clipboard just by passing a parameter to it is WAY WAY faster than having to press CTRL + C. But if that's the only way then I'd just go with what I have then.

Comment: @RepeaterCreeper What you believe it's doing and what it's actually doing are 2 different things. Furthermore i seem to recall much more is needed to read from a textarea (setting selectionStart and SelectionEnd for instance).

Comment: @MatthewRath Never mind that. I found out that it was only available by binding it to a button as the below answer indicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the code wont work without user interaction, if you try to run it from the console, it will not work.

the only way to run the code is to bind the function to a button or something like that.

```js
function copytext(text) {
    var textField = document.createElement('textarea');
    textField.innerText = text;
    document.body.appendChild(textField);
    textField.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    textField.remove();
  }
```

```html
<button onclick='copytext("some text")'>copy some text!</button>
```

You can try calling `document.queryCommandSupported("copy")` or `document.queryCommandEnabled("copy")` from the dev console as well as from buttons to verify this.

[Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/04/cut-and-copy-commands?hl=en#known-bugs)

See the known bugs section at the bottom.

Comment: So it's not possible from console then? Anyone here to confirm that? Code works for me. :P

Comment: You can try calling `document.queryCommandSupported("copy")` or `document.queryCommandSupported("copy")` from the dev console as well as from buttons to verify this.

Comment: @HenryArneson Returns false for chrome, returns true for FireFox.

Comment: oops my comment meant to say document.queryCommandSupported("copy") and document.queryCommandEnabled("copy")

Comment: supported returns true but enabled returns false

Comment: @HenryArneson Even still firefox is not copying text to clipboard.

Comment: @RepeaterCreeper right it needs to be called by user interaction (ex. a button). as shown by the output of `document.queryCommandEnabled("copy")`

Comment: @HenryArneson Ugh that sucks. Do you know any way to fool the system on thinking I was pressing a button?

Comment: @HenryArneson Well thanks for the help I have accepted your answer. Thanks for that info. I'm sure other people will find it useful in the future.

Comment: @RepeaterCreeper np! sorry i couldn't provide the answer you were looking for